# instrictContentSize on UILabel returns different values at different instances

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm working on a project in swift 3.0 where I have three UILabels with numberOFLines set to 6 in the UIStoryBoard. Underneath the labels I have placed three UIButtons which function as the "see more" option. At times my code works fine where if the label i truncate it shows the see more button and once clicked it shows the whole content, while at times even though the UILabel content is truncate it still not shows the "see more" button so I'm unable to see the whole content. What am I missing in the code, help would much appreciate.

```
   import UIKit

class MP3ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var descriptionSeeMoreBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var howToUseSeeMoreBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var cautionsSeeMreBtn: UIButton!
    var seeMoreIsShowing =  false
    @IBOutlet var cautionsContentLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var howToUseContentLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionContentLbl: UILabel!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.descriptionContentLbl.sizeToFit()
        self.howToUseContentLbl.sizeToFit()
        self.cautionsContentLbl.sizeToFit()
        getItButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        let mediaID = mediaDetails?["entity_key"] as! String
        let url = URL(string: Config.MP3_LIST + "?mediaId=\(mediaID)")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error!);
                DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                })
            }
            else{
                do{
                    if let urlContent = data {
                        let  serverResponseData = try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
                        if(serverResponseData["error"] == nil){
                            self.mediaDetails = serverResponseData
                            print("Media :",self.mediaDetails!)
                            self.mediaList = (self.mediaDetails?["trackList"]as? NSArray)!

                            DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {

                                self.descriptionContentLbl.text =  self.mediaDetails?["description"] as? String ?? "description...."
                                self.howToUseContentLbl.text =  self.mediaDetails?["howToUse"] as? String ?? "How to use......."
                                self.cautionsContentLbl.text =  self.mediaDetails?["cautions"] as? String ?? "cautions...."
                                let track = ((self.mediaDetails?["trackList"] as! NSArray)[0]) as! NSDictionary
                                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error In Json De-serialization")
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                })
            }
        })
        task.resume();

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadTheInitialLabelText()
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    }

    @IBAction func descriptionSeeMoreButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (seeMoreIsShowing) {
            self.descriptionContentLbl.numberOfLines = 6
            self.descriptionSeeMoreBtn.setTitle("see more", for: .normal)
        }else {
            self.descriptionContentLbl.numberOfLines = 0
            self.descriptionSeeMoreBtn.setTitle("show less", for: .normal)
        }
        seeMoreIsShowing = !seeMoreIsShowing
    }
    @IBAction func howToUSeSeeMoreButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (seeMoreIsShowing) {
            self.howToUseContentLbl.numberOfLines = 6
            self.howToUseSeeMoreBtn.setTitle("see more", for: .normal)
        }else {
            self.howToUseContentLbl.numberOfLines = 0
            self.howToUseSeeMoreBtn.setTitle("show less", for: .normal)
        }
        seeMoreIsShowing = !seeMoreIsShowing
    }


    @IBAction func cautionsSeeMoreButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if (seeMoreIsShowing) {
            self.cautionsContentLbl.numberOfLines = 6
            self.cautionsSeeMreBtn.setTitle("see more", for: .normal)
        }else {
            self.cautionsContentLbl.numberOfLines = 0
            self.cautionsSeeMreBtn.setTitle("show less", for: .normal)
        }
        seeMoreIsShowing = !seeMoreIsShowing
    }

func loadTheInitialLabelText() {
        let DescriptionTextheight = self.descriptionContentLbl.text?.height(withConstrainedWidth: self.descriptionContentLbl.frame.width, font: self.descriptionContentLbl.font)
        if self.descriptionContentLbl.intrinsicContentSize.height < DescriptionTextheight! {
            self.descriptionSeeMoreBtn.isHidden = false
        }else{
            self.descriptionSeeMoreBtn.isHidden = true
        }

        let howToUseTextheight = self.howToUseContentLbl.text?.height(withConstrainedWidth: self.howToUseContentLbl.frame.width, font: self.howToUseContentLbl.font)
        if self.howToUseContentLbl.intrinsicContentSize.height < howToUseTextheight! {
            self.howToUseSeeMoreBtn.isHidden = false
        }else{
            self.howToUseSeeMoreBtn.isHidden = true
        }

        let cautionsTextheight = self.cautionsContentLbl.text?.height(withConstrainedWidth: self.cautionsContentLbl.frame.width, font: self.cautionsContentLbl.font)
        if self.cautionsContentLbl.intrinsicContentSize.height < cautionsTextheight! {
            self.cautionsSeeMreBtn.isHidden = false
        }else{
            self.cautionsSeeMreBtn.isHidden = true
        }

    }

}
extension String {

    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sizeToFit you labels before you set their text values, sizeToFit after their values get set. This alone won't fix the issue though.

I believe what might be happening is your web service is taking too long to return. So while your web service is waiting, the rest of your program is continuing on with its execution.

So you end up comparing empty labels and getting their height and then getting the intrinsic content size of those labels. The intrinsic size is the size of the non-text filled label, and thats less than the height of whatever your function computes for that label. This ends up hiding your buttons.

Then after all that, the URLSession gives you your data and sets the text values for the labels, but the height calculation has already happened.

A quick fix you could try is calling LoadInitialText() inside of your ViewDidLoad URLSession handler, after the label's text gets set.

Comment: your answer absolutely make sense and it allows me to understand the flow but even after I did it still the same result. anything else I could try. However Since this gives me the exact picture of the execution of my code I should recommend this

Comment: It's hard to tell but the seemoreisshowing variable doesn't seem to get set anywhere. Otherwise you could try debugging the height values and the hidden values in those if statements to see what is actually setting the hidden values